# CSS, Bootstrap - irregular div grid

Tags: css, grid

I was wodering how to code this layout:
[Layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6DDU.png)

[Link to layout](http://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/personal-blog-design-template/)

The problem is irregular grid of div's. I tried bootstrap but when I use two rows there is blank space between picture.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question and the sorts of questions that are on topic for the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like masonry grid layout.
You may use plugins like,

http://masonry.desandro.com/

You can find more free plugins like this.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it uses [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to lay out the posts. It is a grid layout library that lays out the elements depending on vertical space.